# Sporadic "an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

Initial deployment of the site works fine.  After about 2-3 hours, the controllers suddenly cannot be instantiated due to a dependency cannot be resolved (or at least that's what the error message tells me).

I have tried various things, but none of which seem to resolve it.  Does anyone have any ideas what I can check?

Comment: hmm, I wonder if it has anything to do with the container lifetime manager, perhaps it's being disposed.

Comment: Is it always the same interface which it complains cannot be constructed? I can't see how Unity would suddenly lose the ability to resolve an interface implementation which it previously had, which is what the error message indicates.

Comment: What LifetimeManager do you use for that interface?

Comment: @Alfred if this solved your problem you should write it in an [answer and mark it as such](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: Given the error message, I don't think this is anything to do with lifetime managers. It seems likely that the third-party library just wasn't registering that particular interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still have no idea what was happening, but i managed to fix it. i was using a third-party bootstrapping library to register my components and mappings. but after rolling my own with MEF, and controlling the registrations myself, the issue went away. i'm guessing it was doing something funky by disposing things when it shouldn't have. thanks for the help.

In case someone encounters this problem using http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/ with the following declaration:

```
    Bootstrap.Bootstrapper
        .With.Unity()
        .And.AutoMapper()
        .And.ServiceLocator()
        .Start();
```

I replaced that with:

```
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
    MEFContainer mefContainer = new MEFContainer();
    mefContainer.UnityRegistry.ForEach(x => x.Register(container));
    container.RegisterInstance<IMappingEngine>(Mapper.Engine);
    mefContainer.AutoMapperRegistry.ForEach(x => x.CreateMap(Mapper.Configuration));
```

where

```
    private class MEFContainer
    {
        [ImportMany(typeof(IUnityRegistration))]
        public List<IUnityRegistration> UnityRegistry { get; set; }

        [ImportMany(typeof(IMapCreator))]
        public List<IMapCreator> AutoMapperRegistry { get; set; }

        public MEFContainer()
        {
            var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog("bin");
            var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
        }
    }
```

Note that IUnityRegistration.Register() and IMapCreator.CreateMap() are defined in the third-party code.  MEF references System.ComponentModel.Composition
and System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting. Will eventually refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Recently we had a similar situation with one of our Interceptors. All of a sudden it would no longer work. We intercept all calls to interfaces defined in assembly X.Y.Z.**dll**. But the OS decided to call the file X.Y.Z.**DLL** after a while. No new deployment happened in the meantime. But all of a sudden the name matching failed. Do you load some assemblies in your configuration by name? Maybe you should check for IgnoreCase in string comparisons.

Another idea: Do you use some kind of cache for your objects? Or a cache based LifetimeManager? If cache items get invalidated after some time you would loose those objects.